# strategy.short does not put in an order however strategy.long does

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im new to pinescrpt and have ran into a problem that i am unable to solve and really need some help. im not sure why  strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, stop = trailingStopLoss) works by placing an order for long however strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, stop = trailingStopLossS) does not place an order. this is part of the code i have now.

```
///  Long Condition  ///

condition1 = close >= sessionHighPrice and isInSession 
condition2 =  (ta.crossunder(high, sessionHighPrice) or ta.crossunder(close, sessionHighPrice) or ta.crossunder(low, sessionHighPrice)) and isInSession
condition3 = lowertimevariable >= sessionHighPrice

// Track whether condition1 has been met in the session
var bool condition1Met = false
var bool condition2Met = false
var bool condition3Met = false

// Check for condition1 and set condition1Met to true when it's met
if condition1[Timeequal5m] and not inSession
    condition1Met := true

// Check for condition1 and set condition1Met to true when it's met
if  condition1Met and condition2[Timeequal5m] and not inSession
    condition2Met := true


if  condition2Met and condition3[0] and not inSession
    condition3Met := true

var bool crosscondone = false
trailingStopLoss = 0.0
stopvalue_long = 0.0

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
        if (high < partialExitPriceper)
            trailingStopLoss := math.max(perstop1, trailingStopLoss[1])
        else if crossoverConditionper and not crosscondone //(high >= partialExitPriceper and high < SetTrailingper)
            trailingStopLoss := math.max(entryprice, trailingStopLoss[1])
            crosscondone := true
        else if (high >= partialExitPriceper)
            stopvalue_long := math.max(high - ((trailingOffset / 100) * entryprice), entryprice)
            trailingStopLoss := math.max(stopvalue_long, trailingStopLoss[1])



///   Short Condition  ///

condition1S = close <= sessionLowPrice and isInSession 
condition2S =  (ta.crossover(low, sessionLowPrice) or ta.crossover(close, sessionLowPrice) or ta.crossover(high, sessionLowPrice)) and isInSession
condition3S = lowertimevariableS <= sessionLowPrice

// Track whether condition1 has been met in the session
var bool condition1SMet = false
var bool condition2SMet = false
var bool condition3SMet = false
var bool flag_condition3SMet = false

// Check for condition1 and set condition1Met to true when it's met
if condition1S[Timeequal5m] and not inSession
    condition1SMet := true

// Check for condition1 and set condition1Met to true when it's met
if  condition1SMet and condition2S[Timeequal5m] and not inSession
    condition2SMet := true


if  condition2SMet and condition3S[0] and not inSession
    condition3SMet := true

var bool crosscondoneS = false
trailingStopLossS = 0.0
stopvalue_short = 0.0

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
        if (low > partialExitPriceperS)
            trailingStopLossS := math.min(perstop1S, trailingStopLossS[1])
        else if crossoverConditionperS and not crosscondoneS
            trailingStopLossS := math.min(entryprice, trailingStopLossS[1])
            crosscondoneS := true
        else if (low <= partialExitPriceperS)
            stopvalue_short := math.min(low + ((trailingOffset / 100) * entryprice), entryprice)
            trailingStopLossS := math.min(stopvalue_long, trailingStopLossS[1])




///   Execute Strategy  ///

if condition1Met and condition2Met and condition3Met and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, stop = trailingStopLoss)


if condition1SMet and condition2SMet and condition3SMet and strategy.position_size != 0
    strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, stop = trailingStopLossS)


if strategy.position_size > 0
    if low < trailingStopLoss
        strategy.close("Long", comment = "Stop Loss 100", qty_percent = 100)

if strategy.position_size < 0
     if high > trailingStopLoss
         strategy.close("Short", comment = "Stop Loss 100", qty_percent = 100)
```

i have checked the conditions and it seems to be running fine for both short and long, im not sure if my code is clashing thats why im unable to enter a short or what i should do

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `strategy.entry()`?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.order` function place the order in the desired direction with size = 1 by default.

In your code `strategy.order(short)` calls only if `strategy.position_size != 0`, and `strategy.order(long)` calls in backtesting always first because `strategy.position_size != 0` can be true only if strategy have open trade.

So your strategy firstly open long order with size 1 (since you do not define orders size), then call `strategy.close()` for long, or `strategy.order(short)` in any case its only closed you current position, because `strategy.order(short)` calls with default size = 1, so your opened long +1 position closes by calls short -1 position, since to go short you should sell all your current contracts, and you position size again 0.

So if you want to go to opposite your current position you need to create opposite order with size greater than current position or use `strategy.entry()` as mentioned in comment above.

`strategy.entry()` automatic calcs position size for go to desired direction with defined size by adding to order current position size.